Axios on localhost crushes with a timeout error
i׳m working with axios for my api calls and sometimes on localhost axios stucks and falls on a timeout error.
when i tried it on production it does not do it.
Things i tried to do:

change axios versions.

reset the internet, reset the vscode, reset the computer.

tried to add content type to the headers.



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
